# see if all elements in a Java collection end with one of the members of a List

Tags: java, lambda, collections

I have a List of File in Java 11.
I want to check in a one-liner solution if all the files end with one of the extensions listed in a collection.
So I have
`List<File> filesInOutput`
and
`List<String> wantedExtensions`
with elements ".html" and ".png".
I want to check whether all the files in filesInOutput end with either ".html" or ".png", if the filesInOutput contains a file ending with ".pdf", for example, I want to return false.
I have done this code:

```
boolean allMatch = true;
 for(File fileInOutput : filesInOutput) {
                boolean matches = false;
                for(String wantedExtension : wantedExtensions) {
                    matches = fileInOutput.getPath().endsWith(wantedExtension);
                    if (matches) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!matches) {
                    allMatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
return allMatch;
```

Ideally I would like to do this with `filesInOutput.stream().filter()...` in a one-line solution, but the fact that the extensions we admit are in a collection makes this solution harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still a double loop, but a lambda :)

```
        Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<>(wantedExtensions);

        filesInOutput.stream()
            .map(file -> file.getPath())
            .allMatch(filePath ->
                extensions.stream()
                    .anyMatch(filePath::endsWith));
```

Of course you want something like this:

```
        Set<String> extensions = new HashSet<>(wantedExtensions);

        filesInOutput.stream()
            .map(file -> getExtension(file.getPath()))
            .allMatch(extensions::contains);
```

You just need to come up with a method to get the extension. If you search you can find some options on SO using regex or the approach in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run this myself, and maybe this can be improved, but I think this should work, shouldn't it?

```java
Boolean allMatch = filesInOutput.stream().map(file -> file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf("."))).allMatch(name -> wantedExtensions.contains(name));
```

Streams conveniently give us an `allMatch` operator

Comment: A good answer too. The only thing that might go wrong is the file did not contain a dot.